Transient errors and GORM
If a transient error occurs (e.g., a network glitch, a write conflict, a lock acquisition failure, etc.), GORM will return the error to the caller without retrying. It's up to the developer to implement retry logic.
Questions:

Why isn't retry logic part of GORM as many database drivers offer this functionality?

Are there plans to introduce retry functionality in GORM?


Several SQL database drivers and libraries include built-in retry logic for transient errors. Here are some of them:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
Npgsql
pgx (Go)
node-postgres (pg for Node.js)
MySqlConnector (.NET)
mysql-connector-python
Entity Framework Core (EF Core)
SQLAlchemy (Python)
Django ORM (Python)

